# PHP Code Sniffer via Grunt is incredibly slow

Tags: php, node.js, gruntjs, phpcodesniffer

I'm having issues with PHP Code Sniffer running inside of a Grunt task.

Everything has been freshly installed. PHP CS runs perfectly from the terminal (run in less than 2 secondes). But when I run it thought a Grunt task (same binaries, config file, params,etc..) it takes over a minute. I tried using [grunt-phpcs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-phpcs) and [grunt-exec](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-exec) (even tried using a subshell $()) always the same result...

```
Execution Time (2016-05-26 00:09:21 UTC)
loading tasks    956ms  ▇▇ 2%
exec:phpcs     1m 0.7s  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 98%
Total 1m 2s
```

I'm on El Capitan, using node 5.11, grunt 1.0.1.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to adapt the `default_socket_timeout` in the `php.ini` for your PHP CLI. This has worked for me:

```
default_socket_timeout = 0
```

See also http://php.net/default-socket-timeout and https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/issues/3627.